# Save SVN user login data for one Eclipse session

Tags: eclipse, svn

I do not want to store my SVN login data in Eclipse permanently. Eclipse should ask me for my user data when trying to access the repository and store the data until Eclipse is closed. After restarting Eclipse I should have to enter my user data again.

Is it possible to store the SVN user login data for one Eclipse session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good question but neither Subclipse nor Subversive plugin support credentials caching this way.

If you don't have other credentials cached by Subversion you can save the credentials and later delete/overwrite the Subversion authentication cache.

On Windows it is located in the directory `%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth` on Linux AFAIR in `~/.subversion/auth`.

Just delete and overwrite all sub-directories and included files.

Comment: It seems that only files in `%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth\svn.simple` need to be deleted.

Comment: It looks like Subversive has now a feature for credential caching within Eclipse.